# Can someone breakdown how the regex for matching ips works

Tags: regex

```
'^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

Can someone break down how all the parts work? Especially what does |1[0-9]{2} do

Comment: |1[0-9]{2} means "or "1" followed by 2 numbers"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An (IPv4) IP address is a *dotted quad*, that is, four numbers between 0 and 255.

What this regex is saying is "Match four numbers between 0 and 255, separated by the `.` character."

The `|` character in a regex can be read as "or", so each entry is:

```
 (
  [0-9]          # a number between 0 and 9
  |[1-9][0-9]    # or, a number between 10 and 99
  |1[0-9]{2}     # or, a number between 100 and 199
  |2[0-4][0-9]   # or, a number between 200 and 249
  |25[0-5]       # or, a number between 250 and 255
 )
 \.)             # followed by a dot
 {3}             # three times
 ([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]) # followed by the same match, not followed by a dot
```

So this'd match anything between `0.0.0.0` and `255.255.255.255`, i.e. any valid IPv4 address.

Having done a bit of searching, there's an online tool that'll explain regexes: http://www.myregextester.com/index.php. Enter your regex at the top, check the *EXPLAIN* box, and hit Submit.

Answer (score 1):

It matches four numbers separated by dots where each number is between 0 and 255 (inclusive).

Lets break it down for readability:

```
^                     # match the start of the string
(                     # start capturing group 1
  (
    [0-9]|            # either 0-9, or
    [1-9][0-9]|       # 1-9 followed by 0-9, i.e. 10-99, or
    1[0-9]{2}|        # 1 followed by 0-9 followed by 0-9, i.e 100-199, or
    2[0-4][0-9]|      # 2 followed by 0-4 followed by 0-9, i.e. 200-249, or
    25[0-5]           # 25 followed by 0-5, i.e. 250-255
  )
  \.                  # a dot
){3}                  # repeat capturing group 1, 3 times
(
  [0-9]|              # either 0-9, or
  [1-9][0-9]|         # 1-9 followed by 0-9, i.e. 10-99, or
  1[0-9]{2}|          # 1 followed by 0-9 followed by 0-9, i.e 100-199, or
  2[0-4][0-9]|        # 2 followed by 0-4 followed by 0-9, i.e. 200-249, or
  25[0-5]             # 25 followed by 0-5, i.e. 250-255
)
$                     # match the end of the string
```

The pipe character `|` is the `OR` operator.
`{n}` means: "repeat whatever came before `n` times".

Can you spot why the second half of the regexp is there? Why can't we repeat the first half `4` times instead of `3`?

Answer (score 0):

[0-9] Range of accepted values. In this case 0-9
{}    This is a regular expression quantifier. For example {2} means exactly 2 characters.
|     This is OR. For example a|b is a OR b.
^     Start of string
$     End of string

So |1[0-9]{2} means the number '1' followed by 2 digits in the range 0-9.

Look [here](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) for a quick reference of regex